# Combine unbounded multiple point features into 1 point feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop

Is there any way that I can combine multiple point features into 1 point feature?

I tried 'Union' and 'merge', but neither of them works?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If they are all the same point (coordinates), use the Dissolve tool on a common field.

If not, try the Feature To Point tool, you can input your points, and it will return a centralized location

Comment: Nope. They all are different points.

Comment: Try the Feature To Point tool, you can input your points, and it will return a centralized location